# fail2ban regex for openvpn access server

Tags: openvpn, fail2ban

I recently built a personal OpenVPN access server that I use for securing my cell phone when on public wifi.  The VPN piece is working great but I'd like to lock down OpenVPN itself using fail2ban(which is currently in use for ssh on the server).  However, all the fail2ban configurations I can find with Google seem to be for the community edition, not access server.

Access Server doesn't appear to log auth failures to a log file by default, but I got the failed auths to write to the log by adding the following to as.conf

```
DEBUG_LOGDB=1
```

Now, when I generate a failed login for the web GUI, I get the following in /var/log/openvpnas.log

```
2018-05-15 03:24:14+0000 [-] LOG ERR: 'LOG_DB RECORD {"username": "daffyduck", "node": "openvpnas2", "service": "WEB_CLIENT", "real_ip": "123.123.123.123", "timestamp": 1526354654, "start_time": 1526354654, "session_id": "lW7IVKadsgfb6NTR74", "auth": 0, "error": "local auth failed: no stored password digest found in authcred attributes: auth/authlocal:35,web/http:1609,web/http:750,web/server:127,web/server:134,xml/authrpc:110,xml/authrpc:164,internet/defer:102,xml/authsess:50,sagent/saccess:86,xml/authrpc:244,xml/authsess:50,xml/authsess:103,auth/authdelegate:308,util/delegate:26,auth/authdelegate:237,util/defer:224,util/defer:246,internet/defer:190,internet/defer:181,internet/defer:323,util/defer:246,internet/defer:190,internet/defer:181,internet/defer:323,util/defer:245,internet/defer:102,auth/authdelegate:61,auth/authdelegate:240,util/delegate:26,auth/authlocal:35,util/error:61,util/error:44"}'
```

However, I'm not sure how to turn that file into a regex/configuration that fail2ban can use to blacklist IP addresses after enough failed authentication requests.

Can someone assist with generating the fail2ban conf file?  Or is there a better way to restrict failed logins on openvpn that doesn't involve fail2ban?

Edit:

The final working regex I settled on with this setup is:

```
failregex = ^.*LOG ERR.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*\"auth\": 0,.*
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm in a hurry to do it for you completely, but this link will help you: https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_fail2ban_with_OpenVPN

Comment: Thank you for the link, unfortunately I tried that prior to posting here.  That configuration is for OpenVPN, not OpenVPN Access Server and doesn't work on Access Server.

Comment: Well, it just cannot NOT to work :) You need to change `logpath` to `/var/log/openvpnas.log` and then write appropriate regex to catch your log entries and it _must_ work :) Will check it this weekend.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I had updated the log path and made an attempt at updating the regex, and it's still not working.  I will concede that I am no regex expert so I am not 100% certian whether I screwed up the regex or some other configuration in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/openvpnaccess.local** and put there this:

```
# Fail2Ban filter for OpenVPN access server

[Definition]
failregex = ^ .*LOG ERR.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*
```

Test if regex works:

```
sudo fail2ban-regex --print-all-missed  /var/log/openvpnas.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/openvpnaccess.local /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/openvpnaccess.local > missed.txt
```

Yes, it has to be repeated TWO times and after it works, you can see all missed log entries in `missed.txt` file. If everything works, i.e. required log lines are not in the missed.txt file, then:

Create **/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/openvpnaccess.local** and put there this:

```
[openvpnaccess]
enabled  = true
port     = 1194  # change to which one you use
protocol = udp   # change to which one you use
filter   = openvpnaccess
logpath  = /var/log/openvpnas.log
maxretry = 3
```

Check more here: [Developing Fail2Ban Filter Regular Expressions](https://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#developing-filter-regular-expressions)

Site were you can test your regexes: https://regex101.com

Let's see if it works.

Comment: Ok, this has to be user error.  Initially fail2ban-regex didn't catch any of the failures, however I removed the space between "^ .*" so the regex reads as follows "^.*LOG ERR.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*" and the fail2ban-regex command works.  However, multiple failed logons with the VPN or via the web gui do not result in blocking my IP.  I've tried it on port 443(web gui) and 1194(vpn) with both UDP and TCP, no luck.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your version of fail2ban? Enter `fail2ban-client -V` in terminal to see. And what is your `bantime` parameter at `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` if you have `.local` version or at `jail.conf` if you don't?

Comment: Fail2Ban v0.9.3

Copyright (c) 2004-2008 Cyril Jaquier, 2008- Fail2Ban Contributors
Copyright of modifications held by their respective authors.
Licensed under the GNU General Public License v2 (GPL).

Written by Cyril Jaquier <cyril.jaquier@fail2ban.org>.
Many contributions by Yaroslav O. Halchenko <debian@onerussian.com>.

Comment: jail.local the bantime = 604800.  Yes I know it's a bit excessive, but there are only 2 people using this box and if the other one gets locked out they can call me to get unblocked.

Comment: Found it!  I renamed /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/openvpnaccess to /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/openvpnaccess.local and all is right in the world again.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Stupid me :))) You are right, I will edit my answer. Thanks and glad we solved it :)

Comment: Also, edited my original post.  I misread the logs and needed to update the regex for this.  Apparently it throws a line entry beginning with "LOG ERR" for successful and unsuccessful logins.  However, there's an "Auth" field in the logs, 0 = unsuccessful and 1 = successful.  Shared the tweaked regex in my first post

Answer (score 1):

This answer assume a fresh installation of OpenVPN Access Server and Fail2Ban.

**Date of testing :** 10th of August 2018

**Platform used :** Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

**Fail2Ban version :** 0.9.3

**OpenVPN Access Server Version :** 2.1.4b

First, you need to add this option to the *as.conf* file in order to have logs that can be used by Fail2Ban :

```
sudo nano /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/as.conf

DEBUG_LOGDB=1
```

Restart the OpenVPN Access Server service :

```
sudo service openvpnas restart
```

Then, it is recommended to create a copy of the *jail.conf* file named *jail.local* and put changes into this file :

```
sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

After that, you edit the jail.local file and add these lines in the JAILS section. fail2ban regex are set inside jails but a filter file can be configured. Each regex can determine which service put the failed auth log :

```
[openvpnas-web-client]
enabled = true
port = 943
protocol = tcp
filter =
failregex = .*LOG ERR.*WEB_CLIENT.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*
logpath = /var/log/openvpnas.log
maxretry = 3

[openvpnas-web-admin]
enabled = true
port = 943
protocol = tcp
filter =
failregex = .*LOG ERR.*WEB_ADMIN.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*
logpath = /var/log/openvpnas.log
maxretry = 3

[openvpnas-tcp-tunnel]
enabled = true
port = 443
protocol = tcp
filter =
failregex = .*LOG ERR.*VPN.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*
logpath = /var/log/openvpnas.log
maxretry = 3

[openvpnas-udp-tunnel]
enabled = true
port = 443
protocol = udp
filter =
failregex = .*LOG ERR.*VPN.*\"real_ip\": \"<HOST>\".*
logpath = /var/log/openvpnas.log
maxretry = 3
```

Note 1 : Each jail will generate a single alert for the concerned service (Web Administration UI, Web Client UI, UDP tunnel or TCP Tunnel) and will issue a ban only for that service.The bantime value is taken from the default value section.

[image]

Note 2 : I configured the tunnel ports TCP and UDP on 443 in order to avoid public network filters. Default values are : 1194 UDP Tunnel, 443 TCP Tunnel, 943 Web Client and Web Admin UI.

Note 3 : This configuration works with LDAP Auth against Samba Active Directory for the OpenVPN Access Server services (my testing environnement)

After that, the fail2ban service has to be restarted

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```